# Jquery Keyboard Navigation - Activate Item On Page Load

Tags: jquery

No jquery experience, just want to get this simple thing working.

I've got images that I can navigate by left/right key on the keyboard. Click in the result frame and you can see:

http://jsfiddle.net/XZT9P/4/

I just want to update this so that when the page loads, one of the items is active by default.  Ideally I'd like to be able to hard code which one.  As it is now I need to press a key on the keyboard to get one (the first one) active.  Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="title"><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/pi1.png"></a></div>
<div class="title"><a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/pi1.png"></a></div>
<div class="title"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/pi1.png"></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
    display: inline-block;
}
.title.active {
    border: 3px solid black !important;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var $title = $('.title')
var o = {
    37: 'prev',
    39: 'next'
}

$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    var dir = o[e.which];
    var $active = $('.active'),
        i = $title.index($active);
    if (!$active.length) {
        $title.first().addClass('active');
        return;
    } else {
        if (dir === 'next' || dir === 'prev') {
            $active.removeClass('active')[dir]().addClass('active');
        } else if(e.keyCode == '13') {
            link = $('.active a').attr('href');
            alert(link); // window.location.href = link;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add the "active" class to one of the links in the HTML as here: http://jsfiddle.net/XZT9P/5/

```
<div class="title active"><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/pi1.png"></a></div>
<div class="title"><a href="http://www.reddit.com"><img src="http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/pi1.png"></a></div>
<div class="title"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img src="http://www.eonhq.com/m/images/pi1.png"></a></div>
```

For a pure jQuery version, you could make the item active on document.ready as in http://jsfiddle.net/XZT9P/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $title.first().addClass('active');
});
```